# Question on the proof of Subadditive Ergodic Theorem in Durrett's textbook.

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, stationary-processes

This came up in Durrett's proof of the subadditive ergodic theorem.

Let $X_{m,n}$ satisfy the **assumptions** of subadditive ergodic theorem, which reads

> 1. $X_{0,m}+X_{m,n} \geq X_{0,n}$

> 2. $(X_{nk, (n+1)k})_{n\geq 1}$ is a stationary sequence for eack $k$.

> 3. The distribution of $(X_{m,m+k})_{k\geq 1}$ does not depend on $m$.

> 4. $ E X_{0,1}^+ <\infty$ for each $n$, $EX_{0,n} \geq \gamma_0 n$ where $\gamma_0 >-\infty$.

In STEP 3 of his proof, he defines $Z:= \epsilon + (\underline{X} \vee -M)$ where $\underline{X}:= \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_{0,n} /n$. He first shows that $\underline{X} = \underline{X}_{m} := \liminf_{n \to \infty} X_{m,m+n} /n$ almost surely for any $m$.
Then he says $$Y_{m,n} := X_{m,n}-(n-m)Z$$ also satisfies the assumptions of the subadditive ergodic theorem since $Z_{m,n}=-(n-m)Z$ trivially does satisfy the assumptions.

My question is : **why does $\mathbf {Y_{m,n}}$ satisfy the assumtions?**
I see that conditions 1 and 4 are trivial to check, but I don't get how the conditions 2 and 3 are satisfied. Sum of two stationary sequence are not in general stationary.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It trivially satisfies the assumptions because it is additive.

Comment: @JohnB I was not sure why Y satisfies the assumptions

Answer (score -1):

2. Note that $Y_{nk, (n+1)k}=X_{nk, (n+1)k}-kZ.$ Since $(X_{nk, (n+1)k})_{n\ge 1}$ is staionary by assumption, it follows that $Y_{nk, (n+1)k}$ is also stationary. One can write out the details using the fact that $Z$ is independent of any finite collection of random variables $X_{m, n}.$
3. is  actually very easy. Just write out the definition and observe that $(Y_{m,m+k})_{k\ge 1}=(X_{m, m+k}-kZ)_{k\ge 1}$ which clearly does not depend on $m.$

Comment: I suspected some independence going on. How can you show that $Z$ is independent of any finite collection of $X_{m.n}$?

Comment: Note that it suffices to show that $\underline{X}$ is independent of $X_{0, n}.$ This follows simply from the definition of $\lim\inf.$ Limit infimum does not depend upon finitely many terms in the sequence.

Comment: Which "independence" are you referring to? Are you saying that $Z$ simply does not depend on $n$ (or $m$)? I think we need "independence" in the probability sense.

Comment: Point 3 is not trivial. For example, if $X=N=Z$ and $Y=-N$ for some normal random variable $N$, then $X+Z=2N$ while $Y+Z=0$ so that $X+Z$ and $Y+Z$ do not have the same distribution while $X$ and $Y$ do.